# private static member in base class being acessed by derived classes

Tags: c++, class, static

I am currently using the old VC++98, and I am facing issues trying to encapsulate a static member declared as private in a base class. I wish that the derived classes **do not** have access to such static member, but I can't find out how. The following example code is compiling and running without problems (whereas it should not, in my opinion):

```
class Base
{
private:
static int integer;
};

int Base::integer=0; //initialization

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
int GetInteger(){return Base::integer;}
};
```

How can I make the static member inacessible in the derived class?

Comment: If possible, upgrade the compiler. MS used to be very bad for not following the standard, and doing their own thing (they're much better now). Also, that compiler is 24 years old, and very outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make the static member inaccessible in the derived class?

Use a compliant compiler. The code doesn't compile in standard C++ (any version) just like you expect.